# Is it Possible to upload a profile Picture along with the registration to the Fire base server?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, firebase

I am working on an Android application which stores the profile picture along with the registration like name, email, phone number, password etc.
The user registration works perfectly.
The problem is that I want to create the profile with all of the above attributes.
I wasn't able to understand how is this possible in a single activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that with authentication. However you can create database instance and add user details based on userId returned from firebase authentication

For example while authentication if i will get userId `fgjhyhsfjk5425`, then i will add data with that key and other details inside it.

```
fgjhyhsfjk5425:{
    name:abc
    profile:url
    age:25
}
```

Comment: it means i have to create another activity to do this unless i have the registration activity as well?

Comment: Make a flow, like when your user registration is a success then execute  adding details to firebase.

Comment: No need to create additional activity for that, once you are done with authentication, take userId and add other data with that id .

Answer (score 2):

Firebase user takes display name and email id of the user. You can save your extra data in firebase database and you can also save the download URL of the profile picture in the firebase database.

Like this:

```
{
  "name@provider,com" : {
    "displayName" : "Full Name",
    "phoneNumber" : 1234567890,
    "profilePicUrl" : "your url retrieved from firebase storage"
  },
```

Add extra details if you want. hope this helps